# Change Neutral Position for Accelerometer in Spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite, sprite-kit, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm making a simple game in Spritekit where I roll a ball around the screen.  Right now it works fine and the ball moves around how I want it to.  I want to change it though so that the neutral position is something like 45 degrees instead of flat.  This is the code I have now.

```
- (void)startMonitoringAcceleration {


if (_motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
    [_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];

}
}

- (void)moveBallFromMotionManager {

CMAccelerometerData* data = _motionManager.accelerometerData;
if (fabs(data.acceleration.x) > 0.05) {
    [_ball.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(25.0 * data.acceleration.y, -25.0 * data.acceleration.x)];
}
if (fabs(data.acceleration.y) > 0.05) {
    [_ball.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(25.0 * data.acceleration.y, -25.0 * data.acceleration.x)];
}


}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {    

    [self moveBallFromMotionManager];

}
```

I'm new to this, so I don't really know how I should go about doing it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Create a baseline for your pitch and roll. For example, at the init method (or anytime you want) set 2 variables with the current value for pitch and roll. Once done, you can use those variables as an offset against current values.

For example, the pitch offset is set at 0.3. If your current pitch reading is 0.45, subtract the offset from the current reading.